# Trouble understanding function composition?

Tags: function-construction, sequence

I made the following code:

```
Cs = {{0, 1}};
f[x_] := (Clear[s]; s = (x[[2]] - x[[1]])/3; Splice[{{x[[1]], x[[1]] + s}, {x[[1]] + 2 s, x[[2]]}}])
```

Observe that we can compose and apply `f` to `Cs` repeatedly.

> [image]

Now If I try to work with composition in any of the following ways:

```
Composition[Sequence @@ Table[f, 3]] /@ Cs
Composition @@ Sequence[Table[f, 3]] /@ Cs
```

The following error happens:

> [image]

What went wrong? I thought that I would be able to use `Composition[Sequence @@ Table[f, 3]] /@ Cs` as a function in the same way I was using `f`.

Answer (score 4):

Since `f /@ Cs === Map[f]@Cs`, we can use `Map[f]`.

```
Composition[Sequence @@ Table[Map@f, 3]]@Cs
```

Comment: But what happened? Why can I used `f` but can't use the composition?

Answer (score 4):

Note that f needs a list of 2 numbers as argument and that cs is a list with one element. Therefore:

```
f[cs]
```

will not work. But the following will work:

```
f /@ cs
```

Now, consider the composition of ff (not f to avoid evaluation):

```
Composition[Sequence @@ Table[ff, 2]][cs]

(* ff[ff[{{0, 1}}]] *)
```

This will not work because the argument of the inner ff is a list with one element and not a list with 2 numbers.

On the other hand, consider:

```
f /@ f /@ cs
```

This will evaluate to:

```
f /@ {{0, 1/3}, {2/3, 1}}
```

and further:

```
{f[{0, 1/3}], f[{2/3, 1}]}


(* {{0, 1/9}, {2/9, 1/3}, {2/3, 7/9}, {8/9, 1}} *)
```